# surveymonkey webhooks creation API giving permission error

Tags: webhooks, surveymonkey

I am trying to create a webhook for my survey using the API -

**https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks**.

However, I am getting an out of scope - permission denied to the request.

P.S. : My account with SurveyMonkey is under GOLD PLAN.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are requesting the webhooks scopes in your app settings.

Go to https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/ find the app you are working with and click "Settings".

You should see a scopes section like this:

[image: App Scopes]

Make sure view/create webhooks are set to required. Then you can use the auto-generated access token, or when doing oauth approve the app and you'll have access to those scopes.